# Create a tree object-structure from HTML header tags

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

What is the best way to create a tree object-structure from HTML header tags? (I am mostly concerned about readability afterwards)

Here is the object I would like to map the HTML into:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Html { get; set; }
    public List<Node> SubNodes { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the sample HTML:

```
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Content under header 1</p>

<h2>H2 for header 1</h2>
<p>Content under H2 for header 1</p>

<h3>H3 for H2 under header 1</h3>
<h4>h4 for h3 under h2 and header 1<h4>
<p>Content under H4 for h3 and H2 under header 1</p>

<h2>Second H2 for header1</h2>
<p>Content under second H2 for header 1</p>

<h1>Second header 1</h1>
<p>Content under second header 1</p>
```

The expected structure should look something like this (written in JSON):

```
[{ 
    'Title': 'Header 1',
    'Html': '<h1>Header 1</h1><p>Content under header 1</p>',
    'SubNodes': [{
        'Title': 'H2 for header 1',
        'Html': '<h2>H2 for header 1</h2><p>Content under H2 for header 1</p>',
        'SubNodes': [{        
            'Title': 'H3 for H2 under header 1',
            'Html': '<h3>H3 for H2 under header 1</h3>',
            'SubNodes': [{
                'Title': 'h4 for h3 under h2 and header 1,'
                'Html': '<h4>h4 for h3 under h2 and header 1<h4><p>Content under H4 for h3 and H2 under header 1</p>',
                'SubNodes': []
            }]
        },{
            'Title': 'Second H2 for header1',
            'Html': '<h2>Second H2 for header1</h2><p>Content under second H2 for header 1</p>',
            'SubNodes': [] 
        }]
    }]
},{
    'Title': 'Second header 1',
    'Html': '<h1>Second header 1</h1><p>Content under second header 1</p>',
    'SubNodes': [] 
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this isn't pretty at all and will probably break if the structure of the `HTML` changes too much, but it seems to the work and maybe it gives you an idea where to start.

First, I'd add the property `public int Level { get; set; }` to your `Node` class to make things easier.

Next, you probably want a method to tell which `Level` a heading has.

I made something like this:

```
bool IsHeading(string tagName, out int? level)
{
  level = null;
  if (tagName.StartsWith("h", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
  {
    return false;
  }

  int tempLevel;
  if (int.TryParse(tagName.Substring(1), out tempLevel) == false)
  {
    return false;
  }

  level = tempLevel;
  return true;
}
```

The algorithm then is something like:

- Get the first heading and set it as current node
- If the next element is not a heading, append its content to the current node
- Repeat last step until the next element is a heading.
- Set the current node as parent node, get the next heading and set that as new current node.
- If the next heading has a higher level, add it to the parent.
- If the level is same or lower, find the last node with an even lower level, and add it to that.
- If there is no lower level node, treat it as a "first heading".
- Repeat

Something like this:

```
  var nodeList = new List<Node>();
  var allNodes = new List<Node>();
  Node parentNode = null;
  Node currentNode = null;

  foreach (var htmlNode in body.ChildNodes)
  {
    int? level;

    if (IsHeading(htmlNode.Name, out level) && level.HasValue)
    {
      currentNode = new Node();
      currentNode.Title = htmlNode.InnerText;
      currentNode.Html = htmlNode.OuterHtml;
      currentNode.Level = level.Value;
      allNodes.Add(currentNode);

      if (!allNodes.Any(n => n.Level < currentNode.Level))
      {
        nodeList.Add(currentNode);
        parentNode = null;
      }

      if (parentNode != null)
      {
        if (parentNode.Level >= currentNode.Level)
        {
          parentNode = allNodes.Last(n => n.Level < currentNode.Level);
        }
        parentNode.SubNodes.Add(currentNode);
      }
      parentNode = currentNode;

      continue;
    }

    if (currentNode == null)
    {
      continue;
    }

    currentNode.Html += htmlNode.OuterHtml;
  }
```

Again, not proud, but something to start from.

Edit 1: Don't know what `rootNode` was about. Not needed; removed.

Edit 2: Oh, it was probably meant to make it work, even if the first heading isn't `<h1>`. Fixed that.

Comment: well, looks better than what i have currently :) This task is a toughy. Interesting that it's not recursive. I adapt it to my code and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: It passed my unit tests! Now to read and understand. I had one variation on your code which makes it more readable (for me at least). I like to hae one method, one task. Therefore, I made two methods for your IsHeading method. The usage then looks like this ´int level = IsHeading(node.Name) ? GetHeadingLevel(node.Name) : 0;
if (level > 0)´

Comment: if you found my question interesting and clearly asked i would love a upvote ;)

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Yes, the `IsHeading` with an out parameter is a matter of taste. My thought process was that a valid heading is an  `"h"` followed by an integer and if I determine that this is the case, then I can also return that integer I just got. -- If you have any questions about the code, feel free to ask and I'll try to answer.

Comment: the only way I could think of doing this was a recursive way. I was surprised that you managed to do this without doing it recursively. When i go recursive, it's always affects the readability.